# Why lxml fails to be installed in a python3.10 environment?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently upgraded from `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` to `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` shipped with `python3.10` and now what worked under `python3.8` doesn't work under `python3.10` release. I'm trying to install multiple packages in a `virtual env` and when it comes to `lxml` I see so many errors:

```
 src/lxml/etree.c:248743:38: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248743 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__FeedParser.tp_print = 0;
             |                                      ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248754:36: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248754 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_XMLParser.tp_print = 0;
             |                                    ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248765:40: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248765 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_XMLPullParser.tp_print = 0;
             |                                        ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248776:44: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248776 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_ETCompatXMLParser.tp_print = 0;
             |                                            ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248787:37: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248787 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_HTMLParser.tp_print = 0;
             |                                     ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248798:41: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248798 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_HTMLPullParser.tp_print = 0;
             |                                         ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248813:43: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248813 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget.tp_print = 0;
             |                                           ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248833:44: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248833 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserContext.tp_print = 0;
             |                                            ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248840:47: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248840 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__ParseEventsIterator.tp_print = 0;
             |                                               ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248855:38: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248855 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder.tp_print = 0;
             |                                      ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248872:49: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248872 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__PythonSaxParserTarget.tp_print = 0;
             |                                                 ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248887:47: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248887 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__TargetParserContext.tp_print = 0;
             |                                               ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248895:45: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248895 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_SerialisationError.tp_print = 0;
             |                                             ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:248906:42: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’
      248906 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree__FilelikeWriter.tp_print = 0;
```

I tried installing `cmake` and `wheel` but it didn't work, I tried to open an issue in `lmxl`'s github repo but they removed the `issue` section. Have you guys encountered this problem and can it be fixed before I will downgrade another time Ubuntu?

Comment: I have same problem with python3.9. Did you found a solution?

Comment: Only solution I did is installing python3.8 alongside my python3.10 installation.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to install *lxml* with pip first you need to install *libxml2-dev* and *libxslt-dev* in your system as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Check if 'python3-lxml' is installed too. After this try to install *lxml* again within your venv.

Comment: They are both installed on the system `libxslt1-dev is already the newest version (1.1.34-4build2).
libxml2-dev is already the newest version (2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1).`

Comment: I think this problem is Ubuntu related, because in Arch Linux I installed lxml version 4.91 without any problem. I using Python 3.10.6.